# Utility to measure width/size of location on screen?

Tags: windows, display

Sometimes, I need to check how many pixels an area takes on the screen.

Does someone know of a utility for Windows that would let me click somewhere on the screen, drag 'n drop to the lower right hand-side of the area, and show the width/height in pixels of the selected area?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**PicPick Tools - All-in-one Design Tools**](http://picpick.wiziple.net/)

PicPick is an all-in-one software for software developers, graphic designers and home user.

It has an intuitive interface and simple, elegant operation. After starting the software, you simply select one of the tool from the PicPick Tools trayicon menu when you want.
It features a powerful capture tool, image editor, color picker, color palette, **pixel ruler**, protractor, **crosshair**, whiteboard and etc. You can use all these tools freely....

Comment: Neat tool! +1 :)

Comment: Yes, thanks, it's a great, free application :-) Use its CrossHair feature to check the width/height of a section on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Not built for this purpose but quite a number of screen capture tools do that.

E.g. [FastStone capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm), [MWSnap](http://www.mirekw.com/winfreeware/mwsnap.html), [!Quick Screen Capture](http://www.etrusoft.com/product.htm) etc etc

Answer (score 1):

You can try [MB ruler](http://www.markus-bader.de/MB-Ruler/index.htm). In coordinate system mode it does what you need.

Another screen measuring tool that comes to mind is [Screen Calipers](http://www.iconico.com/caliper/).

Comment: I cant uninstall MBRuler fast enough. trying to use it on multiple monitor setup was really laggy

Answer (score 0):

[Greenshot](https://getgreenshot.org) shows sizes too while taking a screenshot:

[image: Greenshot sizes]

Answer (score 0):

This method should work with all Windows versions to date. It works in 2021.

1. Size the window desired to measure.
2. Screen capture the active window.
3. Paste into a fresh, blank Paint instance.
4. Save the image file, jpg is convenient.
5. Read properties/details of the jpg.
6. You will have the dimensions of the current window size.

I mark, fold, and trim a sheet of copy paper to save the best common dimensions.
Next time I have the sheet overlay and I size the target window behind it.
Hope that helps.

Comment: You actually only need to do steps 1 through 3 - Paint will show the image size in its status bar directly after pasting.